# wp all export add percentage price to xml

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, wpallimport

I am trying to add 11% to the exported product xml price

```
<?php
function shopflix_price($price){
    $percentdiff = 11;
    $price *= (1 + $percentdiff / 100);
    return $price;
}
?>[this is the modal of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMQHD.png)
```

but it doesnt return anything. This is the code i tried

I dont know if im selecting the wrong variable or there is something didnt do correctly in the logic of the code

If there is something wrong and its way to obvious im sorry but i dont know php :P

Answer (score 0):

You could always just times by 1.11 which is 111%, that's if the percentage is constant, which I assume it is from your code.

```
function shopflix_price($price) {
    return $price * 1.11;
}
```